# NodeJS: saving JSON to MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am trying to get JSON from an API and store it into a MongoDB database. 
Obviously, it doesn't work. My app seems to hang around the point where I try to save the data to the database. Please advise what to do.

Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/zak", {native_parser : true});


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


var site = 'http://www.vsechnyzakazky.cz/api/v1/zakazka/?format=json&limit=2';


function getData(cb) {

    http.get(site, function(res) {
        // explicitly treat incoming data as utf8 (avoids issues with multi-byte chars)
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        // incrementally capture the incoming response body
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        });

        // do whatever we want with the response once it's done
        res.on('end', function() {
            try {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Unable to parse response as JSON', err);
                return cb(err);
            }

            // pass the relevant data back to the callback
            cb(
                parsed.objects
               );
        });
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        // handle errors with the request itself
        console.error('Error with the request:', err.message);
        cb(err);
    });

}

function writeData (data, allGood){     

// couple of visual checks if all looking good before writing to db
console.log('writing');
console.log(typeof data);
console.log(data);

db.collection('zakazky').save(data, function(error, record){
if (error) throw error;
console.log("data saved");

});
}

function allGood(){console.log('all done');}

getData(writeData);

// ---------------------
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Does the data appear in the database?

Comment: No. I actually inserted manually some data to test if I setup the DB connection correctly. Upon using 'db.zakazky.find()' I see that test data, but not what I'm trying to save

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the `save()` instead of `insert()`. Change this part and it will work:

```
// this should call insert, not save
db.collection('zakazky').insert(data, function(error, record){
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("data saved");
});
```

Comment: `save` should work fine here. However, some MongoDB drivers may expect second `.save()` parameter to be [an `options` object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#save).

Comment: Thank you @victorkohl. Insert() indeed worked. I am surprised and wondering why, because that's what I've been trying to work with initially and only as a last resort switched to save().
Thank you for your help!